# Iterate through list starting at 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to assign 0-6 depend on the starting day. For example, if Wednesday is the starting day, I should set Wednesday to be 0 then Thursday to be 1, and Friday to be 2 etc...

Here is what I have tried

```
def date_manipulate(startday):
    #df['Month']=df.index.strftime("%B")
    temp_week=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
    week={}
    currentday=0
    offset=temp_week.index(startday)
    for day in temp_week:
        if temp_week:
            pointer=temp_week.index(day)+offset%len(temp_week)
            if (pointer>=8):
                pointer-=7
            week[temp_week[pointer]]=currentday
            currentday+=1
        else:
            break
    return week
```

This do not return the right number(ie:Wednesday is 7), It's iterating 9 times instead of 7 for some reason. I also tried slicing index starting at position 3 [3:] and this will skip the first 2 which is also not what I want. Ultimately, I'm just trying to change the start day of the week to be what I define instead of the fix Sunday hence the function. Once the I get the function working, I will do some sort of if statement to loop through the default week and replace it with this new dictionary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
default_week =['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

def date_manipulate(startday):
    week = {}
    temp_week = default_week[startday:] + default_week[0:startday]
    for index, day in enumerate(temp_week):
        week[index] = day
    return week
```

Output for Tuesday as the starting day (`date_manipulate(2)`)

> {0: 'Tuesday', 1: 'Wednesday', 2: 'Thursday', 3: 'Friday', 4: 'Saturday', 5: 'Sunday', 6: 'Monday'}

**EDIT**

If you meant to get `Tuesday: 0` and not `0: Tuesday` in the dictionary, use

```
week[day] = index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your function by using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this:

```
def date_manipulate(day):
    temp_week=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
    i = temp_week.index(day)
    return dict(enumerate(temp_week[i:] + temp_week[:i]))

>>> date_manipulate('Wednesday')
>>> {0: 'Wednesday', 1: 'Thursday', 2: 'Friday', 3: 'Saturday', 4: 'Sunday', 5: 'Monday', 6: 'Tuesday'}

>>> date_manipulate('Tuesday')
>>> {0: 'Tuesday', 1: 'Wednesday', 2: 'Thursday', 3: 'Friday', 4: 'Saturday', 5: 'Sunday', 6: 'Monday'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the list into its two parts and concatenate them.

```
n = week.index(day)
new_week = week[n:] + week[:n]
```

In the 2nd sub list, it goes up to, but not including n

Answer (score 0):

You have `for day in temp_week:` but the only purpose of this is so that you can turn `day` into an integer by `temp_week.index(day)`. You don't use `day` for anything else.

Why so complicated? Simpler would be `for i in range(7):`,
then just use `i` instead of `temp_week.index(day)`.

Next, `temp_week.index(day)+offset%len(temp_week)`
will take `offset` modulo `len(temp_week)`, which just evaluates to `offset` since `offset` is always at least 0 and less than `len(temp_week)`;
then you add `offset` to `temp_week.index(day)`, which of course sometimes gives results greater than 6.

Pay attention to the precedence of operators and use parentheses where needed:

```
pointer = (temp_week.index(day) + offset) % len(temp_week)
```

Of course the *better* way is to use the slices correctly as in Evyatar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using itertools really easily using `cycle` and `dropwhile`. The logic is `cycle` will create an infinitely long list of weeks, and `dropwhile` will be used to get the first day in the "cycle":

```
from itertools import cycle, dropwhile

target_day = 'Wednesday'
week_cycle =  cycle(['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'])
day_number = range(7)

print(list(zip(dropwhile(lambda x: x != target_day, week_cycle), day_number)))
```

Output

```
[('Wednesday', 0), ('Thursday', 1), ('Friday', 2), ('Saturday', 3), ('Sunday', 4), ('Monday', 5), ('Tuesday', 6)]
```

Or in a function

```
def day_week(day='Wednesday'):
    return list(zip(dropwhile(lambda x: x != target_day, week_cycle), range(7)))
```